# Analysis Problem on Differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that there is no differentiable function $ f(x)$ defined on $(-\infty, \infty)$ such that $f'(0) = 1$, but $f'(x) \geq 2$ for $x \ne 0.$

So I use contradiction method, suppose there exists a function $f(x)$ with those properties, using the definition of limit gives me

$f'(0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \mid \frac {f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}\mid$=1  and $f'(x_0) = \lim_{ h\to 0}  \mid \frac {f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}\mid$ $\geq 2$ for $x_0 \in R$ but $x_0\neq 0.$ I don't know how to come up with a contradiction. Please help.

Comment: derivatives satisfy the  intermediate value property. that means $f'$ must take all values between $1$ and $2.$

Answer (score 2):

You may assume such f exists,

Note that,

$$f'(1)\ge2$$ and $$f'(0) = 1$$

By Darboux's_theorem
, there exists $$y\in(0,1)$$  such that $$f'(y) = 0.5$$ 
however $$y\neq0$$ $$f'(y)\ge2$$ which yields$$0.5\ge2$$. Hence, contradiction arises.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there were such an $f.$ Since $f'(0)=1,$ there is an $x>0$ such that $(f(x) -f(0))/(x-0) <2.$ But for this $x$ the the mean value theorem shows $(f(x) -f(0))/(x-0) = f'(c)$ for some $c \in (0,x).$ So we have found a nonzero point where $f' < 2,$ contradiction.

Comment: How did you come up with (f(x)−f(0))/(x−0)<2 when there is an x>0 ?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}  (f(x)−f(0))/(x−0)=f'(0)=1$ So the difference quotient is $<2$ for small $x.$

Comment: where is the contradiction? You only show the lim is 0, but the MVT equation doesn't have a limit

Comment: The limit is $1$ not $0.$ That means the difference quotient is $<2$ for some $x.$ But by the MVT, that diff quotient is $f'(c)$ for some $c\ne 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Since $f'(0) = 1$, given $\epsilon = 1/2$ there exist $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < x < \delta$ we have

$$\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} - 1 < \epsilon \implies f(x) - f(0) < (1 +\epsilon)x = 3x/2.$$

By the mean value theorem, there exists $0 < \xi < x $ such that

$$f(x) - f(0) = f'(\xi)x \geqslant 2x.$$

We have a contradiction

$$2x < 3x/2$$

and the function $f$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is differentiable everywhere and $f'(x) \ge 2$ for all $x \neq 0$.

It is straightforward to show that
$f$ is strictly increasing everywhere since it is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,0)$ , $(0,\infty)$ and continuous everywhere. Then we must have
$f'(0) \ge 0$.

(By considering $\phi(x)=f(x)-2x$, we see that $\phi$ is non decreasing and hence
$\phi'(x) \ge 0$ everywhere, or $f'(x) \ge 2$ everywhere.)